# undefined reference to `pvPortMalloc'

Tags: freertos

I'm tying to build project with FreeRTOS(last version).
And I have 20170907-1650 version of Eclipse.
And in process of buld I have got the errors what I can't solve by myself.
Cause of what, I asking help in this event.
Pasting list of similar errors:

- undefined reference to `pvPortMalloc'
- undefined reference to `vPortFree'
- undefined reference to `vApplicationStackOverflowHook'

Comment: See the docs https://www.freertos.org/a00111.html and https://www.freertos.org/Stacks-and-stack-overflow-checking.html .. Google is your friend ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in comment, see [Heap Memory Management](https://www.freertos.org/a00111.html), freertos doesn't provide `malloc`/`free` functions.

You'll have to:

- Modify `FreeRTOSConfig.h` to set

  - `configSUPPORT_DYNAMIC_ALLOCATION` to `1`
  - `configAPPLICATION_ALLOCATED_HEAP` to `4` (you can replace `4` according to your needs)
- Add the file [heap_4.c](https://github.com/jameswalmsley/FreeRTOS/blob/master/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/MemMang/heap_4.c) to your project (same remark as above)